# Reviving a product, with a patent, that has not be produced in over 40 years?

Tags: patentability

How could one revive a product with a patent that has not been created in over 40 years? The company that has the patent does not and has not made the product in over 40 years, and I would like to begin making the product again. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents! Could you please clarify your question a bit? What barriers to reviving the product are you concerned with? The patents would all be expired at this point--I'm not sure if that answers your question.

Comment: The patent know how is now in the public domain. You could use it as you wish. Do the product and make money...